# Knockoutjs click binding stopped working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having trouble with my knockoutjs click binding, it seems to have stopped working and I am not sure why. The click binding is in a template as shown below.

The version I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

My template

```
<ul id="runners" data-bind="template: {name:'runner-template', foreach:employees}"></ul>
<script type="text/html" id="runner-template">
   <li class="runner" data-bind="click: runnerSelected.bind($data, Id(), Name())"> 
      <span data-bind='text: Name'></span>
   </li>
</script>
```

My javascript function exists outside of my view model

```
function runnerSelected(id, name) {    
   sponsoredRunner.id = id;
   sponsoredRunner.name = name;
   $("#sponsoredRunner").html(name);
   console.log('~~ click on selected runner ['+JSON.stringify(sponsoredRunner)+']');
}
```

I load the view model from an asynchronous call

```
var temp = {};
temp.employees = [];
for(var i=0 ; i<result.employees.length ; i++) {
   temp.employees.push(result.employees[i]);
}
var results = ko.mapping.fromJS(temp);
ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById('runners'));
ko.applyBindings(results, document.getElementById('runners'));
```

There is no output in the console to let me know where the problem is.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you set up a small example replicating the problem?

Comment: trying to get knockout working in jsfiddle....

Answer (score 0):

The problem was unrelated, I was hiding the ul elements using jquery.blur() on a setTimeout. The timeout was 100ms, turns out that was putting jquery and knockout in a race.

The code became cleaner during this process as well, so posting for completeness.

```
<ul id="runners" data-bind="template: {name:'runner-template', foreach:employees}"></ul>
<script type="text/html" id="runner-template">
   <li class="runner" data-bind="click: $parent.runnerSelected"> 
      <span data-bind='text: Name'></span>
   </li>
</script>
```

And the javascript..

```
result.runnerSelected = function(data,event) {
   $("#runners").hide(); 
   sponsoredRunner.id = data.Id;
   sponsoredRunner.name = data.Name;
   $("#sponsoredRunner").html(sponsoredRunner.name);   
}
ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById('runners'));
ko.applyBindings(result, document.getElementById('runners'));
```

Comment: [find this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranparab0/za1q1zq3/) hope this is what you are expecting..